# python http server - content in multiple packet

Tags: python

I create a http server in python while I learn the http protocol. I ran into a problem. I want to send the content to browser in multiple packets. I tried this:

```
conn.send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK")
conn.send("\r\n")
conn.send("Content-Type: application/force-download")
conn.send("\r\n")
conn.send("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.txt")
conn.send("\r\n")
conn.send("Content-length: "+str(file_length))
conn.send("\r\n\r\n")

c = 0
while download_data[c]:
  conn.send(download_data[c])
```

but it does not work. Browser receives only the first packet. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What is the type of your ``conn`` and ``download_data`` variables?

Comment: conn is socket object and download_data contains parts of content.

Answer (score 0):

i don't see any place where `c` changes, so it's unlikely that the value of `download_data[c]` will change, either.  do you need:

```
c = 0
while c < len(download_data):
    conn.send(download_data[c])
    c += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I write this part code in a hurry. I need edit the header that it has sent all.